# Gulp-sass compressed style doesn't seem to work for me when trying to compile and output sourcemaps

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I'm trying to get my gulp pipeline working for a site but it doesn't seem to want to compress the scss, I've got all the sass compiling into a single css file but the file isn't compressed. I tried changing the raw files under node_modules thinking it may refresh the cache or something but it looks like this style doesn't work or that it doesn't to what I think it does.

```
function css() {
   return gulp
       .src('./scss/*.scss')
       .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
       .pipe(sass({ style: 'compressed' }).on('error', sass.logError))
       .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**For those who are interested about possible values of** `outputStyle`

- nested
- expanded
- compact
- compressed

f.e. with **Gulp** you could use it like `.pipe(sass(outputStyle: 'expanded'))`

(source https://inchoo.net/dev-talk/tools/sass-output-styles/)

Answer (score 1):

So close, you need to change `style` with `outputStyle` and it should work.

[See examples in the options section for gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass#options).

```js
function css() {
   return gulp
       .src('./scss/*.scss')
       .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
       .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }).on('error', sass.logError))
       .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
}
```